# Pandas: Create a stacked bar plot with a two lists

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have two lists:

```py
list1 = ['100', '50', '25']
list2 = ['0', '50', '75']
```

They equal to 100 at their index.

Trying to create a stacked bar plot, and the x and y axis can be the list variable name, list1, and list2.

I've been toying with this for a while but have little experience with python and pandas. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: **They equal to 100 at their index.** what does it mean? can you clarify?

Comment: Can you clarify your desired output?

Comment: Please se: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples on how to create a pandas minimum reproducible example. You are missing some important information including data you would use as the variable that is stacked.

Comment: @Grayrigel list1[0] + list2[0] = 100 and so on...

Comment: @ScottBoston i would like to show 3 bars, the first one would show list1[0] at 100%, list2[0] would be 0 so nothing would be plotted for list2.... list1[1] would show a bar with 50 and another bar for list2[1]  with 50, and lastly, a third bard with list1[2] showing 25 and list2[2] showing 75. so basicallly 3 bars that equal to 100...

Comment: https://ibb.co/JHpP3w2 this is a very poor job of what im trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

list1 = ['100', '50', '25']
list2 = ['0', '50', '75']

df = pd.DataFrame({'list1':list1,
                  'list2':list2})

df = df.astype(int)
df.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Output:

[image]